# Qt Application has finished, is good or bad?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, debugging

On QtCreator terminal I use to see

```
application exited with code 0
```

I understand that's normal exit.

I also have seen

```
application has unexpectedly finished
```

Which I understand means there is something wrong.

I also have seen

```
application crashed
```

Also means something is wrong.

But now I'm debugging a Qt5 project on macOS and when it hits a breakpoint then the application closes and on the terminal I see

```
application has finished
```

What does this tells me?

Given the application closes, it clearly is not good but how does it contrast with the other messages? What might be causing it?

Answer (score 1):

**Application exited with code 0:**

This is obtained when closing:

- with the red square on top of the integrated output
- the system close button for GUI apps
- ctrl+c on console apps (on Mac & Linux, not sure about windows this stops the program)

**Application crashed or has unexpectedly finished:**

You get this one when closing a terminal window with my running program. when you quit the terminal without the process, the terminal has no choice but to force it to shut down.

**Application has finished:**

This one appears when reaching a breakpoint (a special line in debug mode, click on its number to make it one, it will have a red dot).

*So to answer your question,* you probably made an unintentional breakpoint somewhere, you can click the red dot to turn it back.

Comment: I reached this issue after deleting all breakpoints and adding one in a slot function, so I'll call it intentional.

Comment: Any idea why the application is closing?

Comment: Do you have a reference? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: If you're still here even with my inactivity, thank you. I wish I could help you more, but I haven't found any reference, this is all how I noticed it would quit depending on what I used (I am also on Mac).